# Auto scroll left to right based on mouse selection

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have a `angular directive` which allows me to select the content of the table cells. Its working fine as expected.

But When I try to select multiple cells in one go scrollbar is not moving so I am not able to select the cells.

> [**Stackblitz Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-area-selection?file=app%2Ftable-selection-example.html)

As you can see in below image I am selecting the cells but scrollbar is not moving to bottom or right. Its Not allowing me to select all the desired cells. (cells with green background are selected cells)

[image]

> **Update: More clarity about the issue**
>
> **I can select multiple cells. But scrollbar is not moving right or bottom while selecting multiple cells. So not able to select the cells
> which are not visible in the view. I am able to select the cells which
> are visible in the current view**

Comment: Did you try with jquery?

Comment: @Rohith No. Its Angular application

Comment: I don't understand your problem. You can't select multiple cell because it dont scroll once you select 1 cell ?

Comment: @MaquessimeChevallier I can select multiple cells. But scrollbar is not moving right or bottom while selecting multiple cells. So not able to select the cells which are not visible in the view. I am able to select the cells which are visible in the current view

Comment: So if you click first row, first col with a ctrl+click you cannot scroll right to select first row, last element ?

Comment: @MaquessimeChevallier Yes  exactly.. If 4 columns are visible then I can select only those not remaining items.

Comment: Did you tried another browser ? Because if I understood the issue, it works in MS Edge.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228799/discussion-between-maquessime-chevallier-and-iamgrooot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `MouseEvent#clientX`, `Element.clientWidth` and `Element#scrollLeft` or `Element#scrollTo` you can do the trick. See the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-area-selection-bad6ie?file=app%2Frange-selection.directive.ts)